# Upgrade from 16.04LTS to 17.10

Tags: upgrade

Is it possible to upgrade my 16.04LTS system to 17.10 without setting up a new system?

I'm search for a solution like `apt-get upgrade`.

Comment: Why do you want this upgrade? Please notice that 17.10 is only supported for 9 months, while Ubuntu 16.04 LTS is supported for 5 years. It is better to wait until August 2018 and the first point release of the next LTS version, 18.04.1 LTS.

Comment: What I tend to do is *not* upgrade, but make some room on the storage medium (hard disk) for a new partition. There I install a non-LTS Ubuntu alongside an LTS one, so that I can boot the LTS one at any time, in case the non-LTS one gets into any trouble.

Comment: You would need to first upgrade to 16.10 (which is already EOL), and then 17.04, prior to upgrading to 17.10. That is the supported upgrade path. The only supported upgrade path which involves skipping releases (which isn't really) is upgrading from one LTS to the following LTS.

Answer (score 0):

This looks like a simple "Just google it" question.  Anyway, you will get step-by-step instructions on [Upgrade Ubuntu desktop | Ubuntu tutorials](https://tutorials.ubuntu.com/tutorial/tutorial-upgrading-ubuntu-desktop#0).

This boils down to:

- make a backup
- run `software-properties-gtk`, in "update" tab set "Notify me of a new Ubuntu version" dropdown menu to "For any new version". *This is the part that clobbers the support duration.*
- run `update-manager`
- Click Upgrade and follow the on-screen instructions.

[image: update manager offering upgrade to 17.04]

Yet I wouldn't recommend you to do it and second @sudodus comment which warns you that by doing so you'd replace a long-term-support system with a system supported only for a short time.

Comment: "Yet I wouldn't recommend you to do it and second @sudodus comment which warns you that by doing so you'd replace a long-term-support system with a system supported only for a short time."  If you don't know how to upgrade or why upgrading to non-LTS isn't a good idea (if it's even possible -- the upgrade from 16.04 to 17.10 is very likely to break your system in a myriad of creative ways), you should stick to LTS, for certain.

Comment: I ran a backup of a 16.04 laptop just to try this, first by going to 17.04.  (Used an external disk cloning device to copy the SSD to another one).  While 17.10 is interesting, it is also different internally.  There are several customizations I have made to 16.04 LTS that didn't make it, and rather than do all that work again for a short-term release I ended up just swapping back to the copy of the original SSD to get back to the 16.04 LTS that is nice and stable. Will wait for the next LTS and probably begin with a fresh install on a new SSD when it comes.